# Does rebuilding a PDF from Tex keep embedded video?

Tags: pdf, media9, multimedia

I am investigating Tex as a possible solution to a problem I have: Currently I build PDFs from Microsoft Word and insert lots of legacy videos into them after the fact in a second step (reasons why this has to be legacy video are given in a separate question I will post later). Then if I make an edit to the document larger than what will fit on a page, I have to rebuild the document and insert the videos all over again, a tedious, time-consuming task, since I have a great many videos, all with several required parameters that must be specified individually for each video clip again and again. It is my understanding that Tex documents are built from a markup language. Does this mean:

(a) that the information specifying each video clip (file name, embed in document, open in a floating window, keep open till closed by the user, show video controls, use no poster), after being placed in the appropriate spot in the source text, will be sufficient to cause the text to be embedded in the resulting PDF with all the desired display and behavioral properties?

and therefore

(b) that repeated generations of the document will not have to be followed by laboriously inserting all the videos and their parameters in a separate, subsequent step?

P.S. To see what I want this to look like, you can go to the following link and open the document entitled 'AcroReaderMediaIcons.pdf'.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bupg31ljzw3s0vz/AAA6CG2pJErre_kjnM-x1DKQa?dl=0(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Yes, (a) and (b) is true for LaTeX documents which use suitable mark-up for inserting this kind of material.

Comment: So far, so good. Dumb question, but how do I get started trying this out? (Meanwhile, I'll be reading the 'Related' posts listed in the column at right.) -Peyton Todd

Comment: You will have to install a TeX distribution. This should get you started: https://www.tug.org/texlive/. But note that TeXLive-2014 is not maintained anymore, but the TeXLive-2015 release is in preparation and should happen tomorrow. After installation, try the examples in the media9 documentation.