# Can LATEX generate the kinds of video I seek?

Tags: media9

The research I've done so far shows me that LATEX can solve one problem I have faced with my current Microsoft-Word-to-PDF workflow: with LATEX I would no longer have to re-insert all my numerous video clips and their several parameters each time I make a major edit to my documents.

The problem I still face is that the default PDF video interface obscures the sub-titles on my videos with its on-screen control bar, and lacks the frame-by-frame viewing capability my readers will need.

To see what I'm aiming for, you can go to the Dropbox link below, save the PDF you encounter there to your PC, and run it from there (the icons don't work if run from your browser):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8hvva3yeaqqmrw/AcroReaderMediaIcons.pdf?dl=0

As you can see, the interface offered by the legacy MOV file in this PDF keeps the controls off the main screen, and allows frame-by-frame viewing using the little arrows at the lower right. But rumor has it that Adobe will eventually block legacy media entirely.

However, based on Alexander Grahn's media9.pdf, I'm thinking LATEX can  solve these problems:

### Being able to see my sub-titles

It looks as though VPlayer.swf has no controls at all, so this problem would automatcally be solved. Is that correct?

### Frame-by-frame viewing

1. It looks like a button-actuated play(number) function could provide this with the number parameter specified as currentTime + 1/30 for 29.97 fps video. Is that correct?
2. Setting 'stepping' to true looks like it would solve this automatically, although I prefer buttons to mouse clicks; but maybe both capabilities could exist simultaneously?
3. Apparently the left and right arrows would solve this problem, too, if "seek backwards/forwards" occurs in single frame increments (perhaps only with stepping set to true)? Would that work?

Finally, to save space on pages, I want the videos to open in floating windows. But is it possible to place the control buttons just below the video inside the window itself as with my example at the Dropbox link above instead of on the main page?

Or if this last wish cannot be realized (as I suspect), then are there other kinds of windows - maybe child PDFs opened by clicking a button in the main window - that would contain non-floating video with controls just below their full-size posters, just as would have occurred in the main window? If possible, I would want such windows to be VERY sparse, containing only the poster and controls, and no larger than the poster and its controls, with the main window still visible below.

Comment: Earlier related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249679/can-pdfs-built-from-tex-show-non-flash-videos, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249673/does-rebuilding-a-pdf-from-tex-keep-embedded-video.